# Is there a standard or best practice for mapping local app variables to remote api parameters when calling api methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mapping, api-design

In PHP I typically create a variable map array that I can use to map my local app variable names to remote api method variable names. I use the associative array to create the expected api endpoint string before making the api call.

```
$varmap['local_var_1'] = ('local_name' => 'local_var_1', 'api_name' => 'api_var_1);
$varmap['local_var_2'] = ('local_name' => 'local_var_2', 'api_name' => 'api_var_2);
```

I'm working on my first Javascript app in React and have to pass local app variables to an api. I was about to do something similar but it got me wondering how others handle this.

I wasn't able to find any examples by searching.

What's your recommendation?

Comment: Using PHP to explain what you're trying to achieve isn't very clear. Can you show what you have (maybe the API endpoint) and what your expected result should look like

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use environment variables with the `dotenv` package for instance: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

This way in a `.env` file you can store your API endpoints (and more) and be able to access them throughout you application